# API-Connect is not opening in Cloud Foundry Services or blank page is coming?

Tags: ibm-cloud, apiconnect

I have created an account on IBM cloud. and created resource. IN resource I have API-Connect  which is not opening it is coming as blank page.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/517OO.jpg  https://i.stack.imgur.com/OPBGk.jpg   https://i.stack.imgur.com/7D8tm.jpg

Comment: Add details and show code. If it is not programming-related, open an IBM support case

Comment: thanks for reply Opened case

Comment: Should be closed: Likely an IBM Support Case and not programming

Comment: I've had that bug too... I decided to open another account... I tried deleting cookies, restarting, another browser, etc.. Couldnt find the solution, so I made a new account... It seems to be a bug of IBM that deleted my account.